# How to generate the five of kind or full house using poker dice?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function getTotal(){

var answers = ["A","K","Q","J", "10","9"]

var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];

const side1 = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
const side2 = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
const side3 = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
const side4 = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
const side5 = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
const diceTotal = side1 + side2 + side3 + side4 + side5;
console.log("diceTotal == " + diceTotal)
}
getTotal();
```

Above code is to get the random five numbers like say for assume 'AJK10Q',
Here into the array A - Ace ,K - King,Q-Queen,J - Jack,10, and 9.

How we can generate the different hand possibilities like
Five of a Kind,Full House ,Straight two pair etc..
it would be good if some one can idea or snippet on this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to have 4 of any numbers, then random through them, and pop the card, this way you won't get 5 As or 5 Ks for example.

```
let answers =  ["A","K","Q","J", "10","9","A","K","Q","J", "10","9","A","K","Q","J", "10","9","A","K","Q","J", "10","9"]
let side = []
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++){
 let x= Math.ceil(Math.random()*answers.length);
 side.push(answers[x])
 answers = [...answers.slice(0,3), ...answers.slice(4)]
}
console.log(side)
```